# Is the correct way to leave no unclosed connections?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, t-sql

I'm trying to debug the source of my

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>
> Message: Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 1.
>
> StackTrace:    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.PrePush(Object
>   expectedOwner)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PutObject(DbConnectionInternal
>   obj, Object owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.CloseConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.CloseInnerConnection()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Close()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()

errors that I'm seeing in my log files and that I believe are leading to 502 errors. All my interactions with the database (I'm trying to do this in the most old-school way possible) are like

```
    public List<VersionInfo> GetAllVersions ( )
    {
        List<VersionInfo> Versions = new List<VersionInfo>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SurveyDbModel._conn))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllVersions",con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Versions.Add(new VersionInfo
                        {
                            Id = !dataReader.IsDBNull(0) ? dataReader.GetInt32(0) : default(int),
                            Title = !dataReader.IsDBNull(1) ? dataReader.GetString(1) : String.Empty
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return Versions;
    }
```

Am I doing the `using`s right? Anything nested wrong?

Comment: why did you close the connection? i think after `using` statement connection get closed.

Comment: Can you link the config file? Maybe there's something wrong with your provider/connection string

Comment: Get rid of that redundant `con.Close();` and see if it persists.

Comment: @ragerory So I should never need `con.Close()` inside a `using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SurveyDbModel._conn))`? It's redundant?

Comment: The connection will be closed when it is disposed, yes.

Comment: Correct, what @stuartd said.

Comment: `using(...)` calls the `Dispose()` method (`IDisposable`) of the used object. In the case of a connection, the disposal includes a call to `Close()` already.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving is not because of invalid disposing of connections. By using the using() { } scope you implement it just fine as the connection will be disposed automatically upon leaving the scope. However, GetAllVersions is not a valid operation, either because of the procedure logic being faulty or because it doesn't exist, which is the reason for the error.

If you in fact have a stored procedure named this way (which is not good practice), you should prepend it with exec, like:

```
exec GetAllVersions
```

However, you should rename it to follow common guidelines:
    exec usp_GetAllVersions

or similar, see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/169/naming-conventions-for-sql-server-stored-procedures/ for examples on good naming.

**EDIT 1:**
I suggest that you post your stored procedure together with your question, or that you check whether the stored procedure is runnable in a user session. My money is on that its not.

Comment: When you call a stored procedure, you just supply the procedure name as command text, you don't include "exec".

Comment: That is only true when the stored procedure is the first statement in a batch, which is why it's a good habit to always prefix stored procedures with exec.

Comment: If you type "exec" in front of your stored procedure name in the commandtext, while using commandtype Stored Procedure, it'll look for a procedure named exec. You'll get a message like: `Could not find stored procedure 'exec  `